# Issue in XDocument.Save Method

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, linq-to-xml

I am trying to insert data in existing XMl file. I have the following code.

```
        string file = MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml");
        XDocument doc;
        //Verify whether a file is exists or not
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file))
        {
            doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
                new System.Xml.Linq.XElement("Contacts"));
        }
        else
        {
            doc = XDocument.Load(file);
        }
        foreach (var c in MyContactsLst)
        {
            //var contactsElement = new XElement("Contacts",
            var contactsElement = new XElement("Contact",
                                  new XElement("Name", c.FirstOrDefault().DisplayName),
                                  new XElement("PhoneNumber", c.FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber.ToString()),
                                  new XElement("Email", "abc@abc.com"));
            doc.Root.Add(contactsElement);
            doc.Save(file);
        }
```

The first issue is in first line of code i.e. `MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml");` It gives me an error

> The name 'MapPath' does not exist in the current context

The second issue is in `doc.Save(file);` It gives me an error

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments

I have refer this question [How to insert data into an existing xml file in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398031/how-to-insert-data-into-an-existing-xml-file-in-asp-net)

I am learning **XML**. So, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why `MapPath` does not exist in the current context is because it is a method of `HttpServerUtility` class, and as far as I know, it is not supported on Windows Phone.

Try loading the XDocument like this:

```
XDocument xdocument = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
```

EDIT: You were having an error saving the document. Here is an answer from a related thread:

```
using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
     using (Stream stream = storage.CreateFile("data.xml"))
     {
         doc.Save(stream);
     }
}
```

Comment: @Kajzar Hey thanks for reply. I have checked it. But now the problem is in Save method. It gives me an error.

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Okay, show me how you use the Save method(post code where you call the method). Note that you should delete the "string file".

Comment: doc.Save("~/XMLFile1.xml"); By using this method I am saving my XML file.

Comment: But I have already created my XMLFile1.xml file in my windows phone project. I just want to insert data into this file

Comment: I have changed my code according to your suggestion. It give me the file location C:\\Data\\Users\\DefApps\\AppData\\{A1256902-95B7-495C-BB35-65AAE6B2D48D}\\Local\\XMLFile1.xml 
Where I can get this file ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Kajzer's answer, here is another alternative that may be easier to grasp and use for saving an `XDocument`:

```
string path = "[some path]";

using (Stream stream = File.Create(path))
{
    doc.Save(stream);
}
```

There is just one `using` statement, and you'll only need the `System.IO` class as it provides both the `Stream` and `File` classes for you to use - making this the most straightforward and easiest to understand solution.